# Multiple source files for one header Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have one header file Header1.h with multiple functions that are implemented in separate .cpp i.e. Func1.cpp, Func2.cpp.

So if I only had one header file and one cpp I would write:

```
Func1.o: Header1.h Func1.cpp
gcc -c Func1.cpp Header1.h
```

But writing:

```
Func1.o: Header1.h Func1.cpp 
    gcc -c Func1.cpp  Header1.h


Func2.o: Header1.h Func2.cpp 
    gcc -c Func2.cpp  Header1.h
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> So if I only had one header file and one cpp I would write:
>
> Func1.o: Header1.h Func1.cpp ; gcc -c Func1.cpp Header1.h

No, you wouldn't.  You never put a header file on the compile line: the compiler will find the header file because of `#include` statements in the source file.

You would write this:

```
all: Func1.o Func2.o

Func1.o: Header1.h Func1.cpp 
        gcc -c Func1.cpp

Func2.o: Header1.h Func2.cpp 
        gcc -c Func2.cpp
```

However, this is really not a good makefile.  First, your source files have a `.cpp` extension, which implies that they are C++ files, but you are using `gcc`, which is a C compiler.  If your files are C++ files you should use `g++` as the compiler.

Second, make already knows how to build an object file from a source file so you don't even need to write a rule.

Your makefile can just be:

```
CXX = g++

all: Func1.o Func2.o

Func1.o: Header1.h
Func2.o: Header1.h
```

and that's all you need.